# I want to click on an image and check a box and change the image

Tags: html

I am a super noob at this so bear with me.

I need to be able to click on an image and for it to both change to a different image and check a box. I have worked out code where I can click on the image and check a box but the image won't change. I have also got code for clicking the checkbox which then changes the image. How do I put the code bits together to get the end result?

Here's the code for clicking on the image and checking the box without changing the image:

```
<label for="img1"><img class="img" src="http://www.gettrumpetlessons.com/wp-    content/uploads/2014/01/trumpet_valve_open.png" />
</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="chk " checked="checked" id="img1" name="img1" value="0" />
```

And here's the code for checking the box and changing the image:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changePic(){
if (document.form1.check.checked){
document.picture.src="http://www.gettrumpetlessons.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/trumpet_valve_closed.png";
}else{
document.picture.src="http://www.gettrumpetlessons.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/trumpet_valve_open.png";
}
}</script>
<img src="http://www.gettrumpetlessons.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/trumpet_valve_open.png" id="picture" name="picture"> 
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="checkbox" onClick="changePic();">
</form>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm assuming that it would be better to add the "label" code somewhere into the second code but I don't know how. Any suggestions.

Thanks

J

Comment: Here's a starting point... is this doing what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/D4nWW/ (Did you want the vice-versa as well, i.e. clicking the image changes the checkbox AND the image?)

Answer (score 0):

you can create a function that toggles the image src, switching it with a data attribute of the image. 
Call this function on click of both elements.

In this function, if the image was clicked, also togge the checkbox.
but if the checkbox was clicked, dont toggle since thats default behavior of checkbox.

see below:

http://jsfiddle.net/m3PFK/

```
(function () {
var image = document.getElementById('image');
var radio = document.getElementById('check');

function toggle() {
    var otherSrc = image.getAttribute('data-other-src');
    var src = image.getAttribute('src');
    image.setAttribute('data-other-src', src);
    image.setAttribute('src', otherSrc);

    if (this === image) {
        radio.checked = !radio.checked;
    }
}

image.onclick = toggle;
radio.onclick = toggle;

})();
```

HTML:

```
<img id="image"  src="http://us.123rf.com/400wm/400/400/dixi_/dixi_0901/dixi_090100077/4215731-small-kitten-on-white-background.jpg" data-other-src="http://www.freewallpapershq.com/wallpapers/Small_Kitten_Hope_14673.jpg">
<input type="checkbox" id="check">
```